# AJAX error handling using Spring

Tags: ajax, spring, web.xml

```
 error: function(xhr, exception) {
    if (xhr.status === 0) {
        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (xhr.status == 404) {
        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (xhr.status == 500) {
        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n');
    }
}
```

I'm using AJAX for my project. Here I catch errors and it will popup alerts. But I want to handle xhr error using Spring (web.xml). Is it possible? How can I do it.

Comment: And what would be the end result with "using a web.xml"?

Comment: I want to load the error page. Not the alert.

Comment: Simply redirect to a error page instead of showing alerts.